# Why my UIPopoverController is popping in this way?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I've two buttons on iPad that opens two popups. They are opened with the code:

```
CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:self.addNewFolderButton.frame fromView:self.addNewFolderButton.superview];
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:frame
                                  inView:self.view
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
```

and

```
CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:self.addNewUserButton.frame fromView:self.addNewUserButton.superview];
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:frame
                                  inView:self.view
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
```

but my popView isn't opened in the same kind of way (the link with the calling button in positioned in different way. Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is because you have given permittedArrowDirections as `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny`. Give a specific direction to both and it will work properly e.g. : `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are giving the arrow direction `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny` which mean it could be any, set the specific direction for homogeneous behaviour

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution!